# Theory behind image subtract 0.5 then multiply by 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

```
with tf.name_scope(scope, 'eval_image', [image, height, width]):
  if image.dtype != tf.float32:
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)

  if height and width:
    # Resize the image to the specified height and width.
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(image, [height, width],
                                   align_corners=False)
    image = tf.squeeze(image, [0])

  image = tf.subtract(image, 0.5)
  image = tf.multiply(image, 2.0)
  return image
```

when we do image preprocessing before we send it to the neural network(more specific, GoogLeNet), why they write code:

```
 image = tf.subtract(image, 0.5)
 image = tf.multiply(image, 2.0)
```

what is the theory behind this? why we need this procedure.
If I try to check what it is looked like, using:

```
 plt.imshow(image)
```

The image cannot show up.

Answer (score 0):

They do this to rescale the image to [-1,1] from [0,1]. They want all images in the same format so they require this step.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I got the point of resale, but what I don't understand is: since the value of image pixel is between [0, 1] ( the same format as you said), why they need to rescale to [-1, 1] ( another format), do you know the reason behind this? Is it better for the convolutional network to process the image? or other reason.

Answer (score 0):

The subtraction and multiplication is done in order to scale the images between -1 and 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know why they do this rescale?